# How to Set User-Developed Web Browser as the Default Browser?

Tags: browser

I am developing a web browser in c#.. i need to give option to the user for my web browser as set to Default browser??? how is it possible

Answer (score 3):

On Windows check out this Registry key:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\HTTP\shell\open\command

There's also HTTPS too. You'd ideally want to check this is set to your application and if not then ask to set it.

Comment: ...and not least to provide an option so the user can disable the automatic check for default browser.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\(Default)`.  Or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE if you want it to affect the entire machine (in which case you may need to set the HKCU version too or it will override).